# How to map the data frame as x-axis when plotting a graph with r and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have such a data frame `df1`, to indicate the emotion status of a certain user in a time series:

```
0.00
0.10
0.20
0.00
0.70 
....
```

And another data frame `df2`, to indicate the number of record in `df1` in a certain day:

```
2015-01-02   1
2015-01-03   2
2015-01-04   3
```

i.e, the first value belongs to `01-02`, the second and the third value belongs to `01-03` and so on.

Now I'd like the plot a point graph with date as x-axis and emotional value as y-axis. How can I do that? Furthermore, How to skip all the 0.0 value and just show the value other than zero? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate steps in the solution I propose.  First create a vector `dates` with the sequence of dates used, secondly use `dplyr::filter` to remove the zero values.

For the first step you can use a combination of `lapply` and `rep` as follows:

```
dates <- c(lapply(seq(nrow(df2)), function(idx) rep(df2$date[idx], df2$count[idx])), recursive = TRUE)
```

the `c(..., recursive = TRUE)` is around it to convert the result to a flat vector.

Then combine into a `data.frame` filter and plot as follows:

```
df3 <- cbind(df1, data.frame(dates = as.POSIXct(dates)))
ggplot(df3 %>% filter(state != 0.0), aes(x=dates, y = state)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: got an error `Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(dates) : 'origin' must be supplied` what does it mean?

Comment: i have added `origin = "2015-02-09"` but got this error: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 12407, 12429`. Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Put your data in reproducible examples in the question and I can take a look at what is happening.  The conversion issue is caused by me using the data in the question as strings, and you having them in a different type.  The number of rows issue may be because there is something skewed in your data; I don't think I can help with that.

Comment: I have solved the problem of differing number of rows already. But the conversion issue still exists. I set the `origin` as "2015-02-09" and all the `date` value in `df3` is `2015-02-09` and just the value of seconds are different.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example